# Tutorials for php yii?

Tags: php, yii

yii is quite new framework.I am looking for decent tutorials for it.

If videos are available then it would be just great.

Thanks

Comment: I ve just done a project in Yii. What I  always do when developing with new framework,  is to read and understand a bit about the framework and read code example and then get started with coding. It is not hard. Yii api website is good enough to get you started. Dont be scary to start. Never wait till you understand everything to start a project.

Comment: SO is not a recommendation site.

Comment: correct. Welcome to stackoverflow, user1114509. Refer the FAQ to help you guide what kinda questions are honored about here. Google YII and you'll get zillions of links to scroll through. Read through those, try out samples and then post if you gotta question specific to any concept of YII.

Answer (score 8):

Check out the links below. Also, the docs provided by the [Yii official website](http://www.yiiframework.com/tutorials/) are very helpful in understanding core concepts:

- [Getting Started with the Yii Framework](http://www.larryullman.com/2009/10/31/getting-started-with-the-yii-framework/)
- [Yii Wiki](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/)
- [Yii Quickstart - First App](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/quickstart.first-app)
- [YII related sites](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/98/yii-related-sites/)

**E-Book**

- [yii.1.1.application.development.cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005JCCIAE)

Comment: not sure why this was downvoted.